FreeIPA, Keycloak and Radius with OTP used for Wifi, VPN and Docker registry auth result in logging in hell
we have configured our infrastructure to use FreeIPA for user database, keycloak as SSO auth and Radius as auth proxy.
We use everywhere password + OTP policy.
We have several apps connected to keycloak, that keep their sessions for a while so there is no problem with them, but there are some services that don't work well with it:

WiFi authenticated thru Radius needs each time user tries to
reconnect and then login fails because OTP has changed. Is there a
way to store somehow session for Wifi so it works at least for a day?
Another thing is our OpenVPN - we have set it up that it disconnects
after inactivity - for some people that have unstable connection they
have to log in with new OTP around each 30 minutes.
And most absurd
thing is Docker Registry. We use Keycloak plugin for Docker Registry
login. It just works that it saves user and password and reuses them
each time anything is called to docker registry. It means that each
time we need to pull/push something we need to login again. So it can
be around 10 times for some DevOps people in our company. That's
brutal.

TL:DR
Is there any way to have some kind of session for WiFi, Docker registry or OpenVPN that works at least for 8 hours so we get rid of relogin hell?
Thanks for advices!

Found the solution for OpenVPN. --auth-gen-token [lifetime] generates token that is used to reauthenticate instead of external auth provider.
